# Loops alternative in typeScript

Tags: javascript

In Java , we have Stream class which plays a significant role to replace the loops .

For eg :

```
List<Integer> number = Arrays.asList(2,3,4,5); 
  
    // demonstration of map method 
    List<Integer> square = number.stream().map(x -> x*x). 
                           collect(Collectors.toList());
```

the above code can be written using while & for loop as well .But we prefer to use Stream class to process the collection of objects .

Do we have same Stream kind of alternatives in typeScript as well as i don't want to use loops for any Iterative work in typeScript .

Thanks .

Comment: Unable to understand the reason of downvote .
Can somenone please provide concrete solution or some reference .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript arrays on typescript

```js
let number:number[] = [2,3,4,5]
let square:number[] = number.map(x=>x*x)
```

you can also learn javascript arrays on [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp)

Comment: the link seems helpful

Comment: @Shivanshu also you can mark as solved and/or upvote